# Graph visualization of csv file data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash, dashboard

```
import cx_Oracle
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash import html, dcc
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

import cx_Oracle
import os




#os.putenv('NLS_LANG', '.UTF8')
#dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('localhost', 1521, 'xe')
#db_conn = cx_Oracle.connect('dbid', 'dbpw', dsn)




#cursor = db_conn.cursor()
#cursor.execute('select * from tablename')

#row = cursor.fetchall()
#df = pd.DataFrame(row)
#df.index = list(df[0]) # category
#df.plot(kind='bar', color='skyblue')


#os.putenv('NLS_LANG', '.UTF8')
#dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('localhost', 1521, 'xe')
#db_conn = cx_Oracle.connect('dbid', 'dbpw', dsn)


#cursor = db_conn.cursor()
#cursor.execute('select * from tablename')

#row = cursor.fetchall()
#df = pd.DataFrame(row)
#df.index = list(df[0]) # category
#df.plot(kind='bar', color='skyblue')
#cursor = db_conn.cursor()

#query = 'select * from tablename'
#df = pd.read_sql(query, db_conn,header=0, delim_whitespace=True)



########################################################################


# Load data
df = pd.read_csv('data/20220607.csv', encoding='cp949')
print(df)




# Initialize the app
app = dash.Dash()


app.layout = html.Div([
                        dcc.Graph(
                            id='scatterplot',
                                 figure={
                                     'data':[go.Scatter(
                                     x=df[df['category']],
                                     y=df[df['fee']],
                                     mode='markers',
                                     marker={
                                         'size':12,
                                         'color':'rgb(51,204,153)',
                                         'symbol':'pentagon',
                                         'line':{'width':2}
                                     }
                                 )],
                                         'layout':go.Layout(title='My Scatterplot',
                                                            xaxis={'title':'Some X title'})}
                                 ),
                        dcc.Graph(
                            id='scatterplot2',
                                 figure={
                                     'data':[go.Scatter(
                                     x=df[df['category']],
                                     y=df[df['fee']],
                                     mode='markers',
                                     marker={
                                         'size':12,
                                         'color':'rgb(200,204,53)',
                                         'symbol':'pentagon',
                                         'line':{'width':2}
                                     }
                                 )],
                                         'layout':go.Layout(title='Second Plot',
                                                            xaxis={'title':'Some X title'})}
                                 )
                       ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

This is the code I wrote.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3621, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'category'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testtest.py", line 77, in <module>
    x=df[df['category']],
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3505, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'category'
```

Error when executing code.

I wanted to directly import the data in Oracle db, but it is difficult to implement with my ability, so I want to convert it into a csv file and implement it.

I think there is an error in the process of loading the column because I made the wrong code.

Which part should I check?

=======================================

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

```
testtest.py:8: UserWarning: 
The dash_html_components package is deprecated. Please replace
`import dash_html_components as html` with `from dash import html`
  import dash_html_components as html
testtest.py:9: UserWarning: 
The dash_core_components package is deprecated. Please replace
`import dash_core_components as dcc` with `from dash import dcc`
  import dash_core_components as dcc

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testtest.py", line 65, in <module>
    df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 8839, in apply
    return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 727, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 851, in apply_standard
    results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 867, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)
  File "testtest.py", line 65, in <lambda>
    df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5575, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py", line 182, in __get__
    accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\accessor.py", line 177, in __init__
    self._inferred_dtype = self._validate(data)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\accessor.py", line 231, in _validate
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a category column in the file? Because the key error is coming from pandas, meaning that you do not have a column with that name. If you do have the column when you first read(cheack through debug), try `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())` because maybe the column name have a space added at the beginning or the end and this line remove it for all columns.

Comment: If you add and execute the code you answered, the following error appears.
When I checked the data, there was no space at the beginning or end of the column name. One column has a space in the value, is this relevant?

Comment: my bad, that one apply to all cells, we want to apply strip to only the headers
`df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` try this one, if an error occurs make sure that are all strings. Also this is just to make sure this is not the problem, since keyerror usually occurs when we try to access some column/row label in our DataFrame that doesn't exist.  And a name having a space is relevant because thats the key that you are going to call to refer to the column and you not knowing that it have space may give you headache.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I don't understand.
I have a terrible headache. Is there any other way?